# Use controller method in ActionCable channel

Tags: ruby, websocket, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I have a rails api that I am trying to create a live stream feature for a git gui. I have a controller and a channel for commit updates and I want to use the live stream function inside the subscribe action in the channel. Is this possible? Or is there a better Rails way to do this. I think the correct way was to use `ActionCable.server.broadcast('commit_updates', { body: return_data })` inside my controller method but I am not calling my controller method anywhere. Where/how do I call it so that it is run on a client subscribing to it? or should I place the logic inside the channel?

here is my commit_updates_controller.rb

```
class CommitUpdatesController < ApplicationController
    include ActionController::Live
    require 'listen'
    require 'json'

    $file_path = "#{Dir.getwd}/.git/objects"

    @@commits = {}
    @@commits_array = []
    @@edges_array = []

    def index
    end 

    def live_stream

        # get folders exlcluding ".","..", "pack","info"
        folders = Dir.entries($file_path).select {|folder| /^[a-z0-9]{2}$/i.match(folder) }

        folders.each do |folder|
            files = Dir.children("#{$file_path}/#{folder}")
            files.each do |file|
                CommitUpdate.find_commit_info(folder, file, @@commits_array)
            end 
        end 
        generate_edges

        ActionCable.server.broadcast('commit_updates', { body: return_data })
        p return_data

        # listens to any changes that happen to the git folder while the program is open
        listener = Listen.to($file_path) do |modified, added, removed|

            #   puts(modified: modified, added: added, removed: removed)
            added.each do |new_file_path|
                split_new_file_path = new_file_path.split("/").reject!{|item| item.empty?}
                folder = split_new_file_path[split_new_file_path.length() - 2]
                file = split_new_file_path[split_new_file_path.length - 1]
                CommitUpdate.find_commit_info(folder, file, @@commits_array)
                add_edge(@@edges_array, CommitUpdate.get_commit_info(folder, file))

                ActionCable.server.broadcast('commit_updates', { body: return_data })
            end 
        end

        listener.start
    
        sleep
    end 

    private

    def generate_edges
        if @@commits_array.length != 0
            @@commits_array.each do |commit|
                add_edge(@@commits_array, commit)
            end 
        end 
    end 

    def add_edge(array, commit)
        if commit[:parents] != []
            commit[:parents].each {|parent| @@edges_array.push({from: parent, to: commit[:sha1]})}
        end 
    end 

    def return_data
        ret = {
            :nodes => @@commits_array,
            :links => @@edges_array
        }
        return ret.to_json
    end 
end
```

here is my commit_updates_channel.rb

```
    class CommitUpdatesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel 
        def subscribed 
            stream_from 'commit_updates'
        end 
    end
```

here is my commit_updates.rb Model

```
class CommitUpdate < ApplicationRecord

    def self.find_commit_info(folder, file, array)
        file_type = self.check_sha1_type(folder, file)
        if file_type == "commit"
            array.push(
                self.get_commit_info(folder, file)
            )
        end 
    end 


    def self.get_commit_info(folder, file)
        author = ""
        parents = []
        commit_message = ""
        unixtime = ""
        decoded_file = `git cat-file -p #{folder}#{file}`
        file_data_array = decoded_file.split("\n").reject!{|item| item.empty?}
        p file_data_array
        
        file_data_array.each do |item|
            split_item = item.split(" ")
            case  split_item[0]
            when "author"
                author = split_item[1..split_item.length() - 4].join(" ")
            when "parent"
                parents.push(split_item[1])
            when "tree"
                next
            when "blob"
                next
            when "committer"
                unixtime = split_item[split_item.length - 2]
            else 
                commit_message = split_item.join(" ")
            end 
        end 

        commit_info = {
            :sha1 => "#{folder}#{file}",
            :parents => parents,
            :commit_message => commit_message,
            :author => author,
            :unixtime => unixtime,
            :id => "#{folder}#{file}",
            :label => "#{folder}#{file[0..4]}...",
            :font => "18px verdana blue",
        }
        return commit_info
    end 


    private

    def self.check_sha1_type(folder, file)
        return `git cat-file -t #{folder}#{file}`.chomp
    end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To use controller's `live_stream`, you need to request this method, for example, write js programme that is calling it periodically. Or some bash script that is calling it. Not good.

Another solution is to put `live_stream` logic into  background job that will check commit updates every X minute. And if job finds change, it broadcasts.

And more common is to place broadcasting in model callbacks `after_save`, `after_commit`. But it looks it is not your solution.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to put live_stream into a background job and broadcast changes? or how to broadcast from model callbacks? I am open to either

Comment: [Implementing Action Cable and Active Job in Rails 5](https://densitylabs.io/blog/implementing-action-cable-and-active-job-in-rails-5) see paragraph "Combining all: sending data through Action Cable". You can put `live_stream` in job.

[Job called from Model callback](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/creating-a-chat-using-rails-action-cable#module-persistingmessagesintothedatabase)